# return argument (struct) from a thread

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I have a function task1 that is called by the pthread_create in the main (pure C). It works but, whatever I do on my_pair is lost after the thread is over. I mean I would like the created thread task1 do operations and save them on eventT.. is it possible to return my_pair? how?

```
void task1(void* eventT){
    //struct eventStruct *my_pair = (struct eventStruct*)eventT;
    // Tried with malloc but same wrong behavior
    struct eventStruct *my_pair = malloc(sizeof((struct eventStruct*)eventT));

    // do stuff
    my_pair->text = TRIAL;
    pthread_exit( my_pair );

}

// Global variable
struct eventStruct *eventT = NULL;


//Calling the thread from the main
eventT = (struct eventStruct*)
thpool_add_work(thpool, (void*)task1, (void*) &eventT);

// Expecting eventT changed (not happening..)
pthread_join( thread, &eventT );
```

Comment: You need to include the code calling `pthread_create`, your problem is likely there

Comment: I added that code, I am using this thread pool:    https://github.com/Pithikos/C-Thread-Pool

Comment: You can only return a `void *` from the thread function, so if you want to return a structure, you have to return a pointer to the data (and the data must survive after the thread has exited, so it can't be thread-local data that is pointed at).  That means either the memory used for the return value is allocated with `malloc()` (and the thread that joins the exited thread must release it or leak), or you tell the thread where to store its result when it is started (pass a pointer to the return value storage when the thread is started).  Or something roughly equivalent to one of those options.

Comment: Technically what you're doing is fine, but the problem is that `pthread_join` is overwriting `eventT`. The second parameter in `pthread_join` receives the value passed to `pthread_exit`, which you aren't calling.

Comment: I edited again adding the pthread_exit but still same behavior.. Jonathan would you suggest how to modify the code to get it working?

Comment: How is 'eventT' defined in your program? From the code snippet provided by you, it looks like that 'eventT' is instance of 'struct eventStruct' [i.e. struct eventStruct eventT;], then, while calling thpool_add_work(), you should pass address of 'eventT' [i.e. thpool_add_work(.., .., (void *)&eventT); Also, you do not need to return anything from your thread. [i.e. printf("Before join()::eventT.text = %s\n", eventT.text); thpool_add_work(); pthread_join(thread, NULL); //Now check if eventT member variable is updated or not, printf("After join()::eventT.text = %s\n", eventT.text);]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example of one way to return a struct from a thread - by passing in an allocted struct for the thread to return.  This example is similar to your posted code, but uses only `pthread` functions since I don't know anything about the `thpool_add_work()` API.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>


struct eventStruct
{
    char const* text;
    char const* more_text;
};

#define TRIAL "this is a test"

void* task1(void* eventT)
{
    struct eventStruct *my_pair = (struct eventStruct*)eventT;

    // do stuff

    my_pair->text = TRIAL;
    pthread_exit( my_pair );
}


int main(void)
{
    pthread_t thread;


    struct eventStruct* thread_arg = malloc(sizeof *thread_arg);

    thread_arg->text = "text initialized";
    thread_arg->more_text = "more_text_initialized";

    //Calling the thread from the main
    pthread_create( &thread, NULL, task1, thread_arg);

    void* thread_result;
    pthread_join( thread, &thread_result);

    struct eventStruct* eventT = thread_result;
    puts(eventT->text);
    puts(eventT->more_text);

    free(eventT);

    return 0;
}
```

Another way this could be done is by having the returned structure allocated by the thread instead of by the caller and passing it in. I'm sure there are many other mechanisms that can be used, but this should get you started.

Comment: Granted I'm using C++, but `my_struct* event = thread_result` gives an invalid conversion from `void*` to `my_struct*`.